# Check if teaser or full content

Tags: theming

I want to add an HTML block inside the node.html.twig file, but only in full content view.

I used the following code but it is not working.

```
{% if view_mode %}
  <div class="article-ads hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/banners/ad.jpg" alt="ad" />
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

I would like to move this code to a Drupal 8 block to avoid editing the template file.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check like this

```
{% if view_mode == "teaser" %}
  <div class="article-ads hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/banners/ad.jpg" alt="ad" />
  </div>
{% elseif view_mode == "full" %}
  //something else
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Why is not working if add this code in node--article.html.twig? Also what is the way to print an html block in twig?

Comment: It should work in all templates.  for block in template take a look at this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207377/programatically-print-blocks-in-twig

Comment: Ευχαριστώ πολύ!